# Get an element through an iterable string (guava)

Tags: java, string, guava

I have an Iterable string (guava library). How can I get elements from it. Here is my code:

```
public static String hillcipher(String str)
{
    String hillcipher="";
    Iterable<String> pieces = null;
    for (int i=0; i<=str.length()-1; i++){
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)){
            pieces = Splitter.fixedLength(2).split(str);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(pieces);
    return hillcipher;
```

here i split  a string into pieces of 2 chars each. for example "java" wil be splided to "ja", "va". But then i want to get each character separatly just to do other calculations on them.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: here i split  a string into pieces of 2 chars each. for example "java" wil be splided to "ja", "va". But then i want to get each character separatly just to do other calculations on them.

Comment: You don't split a string into pieces. Or rather, you're doing it, but you're doing it every time you meet a letter in the string. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I do i run the command and it works. this is not the entire program is a class of it. At the end I will develop a hill cipher function

Comment: If you want to get each character separately, then why aren't you just using each result of charAt?  Why do the splitting at all?

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to get an element from an iterable:

- Iterate over each element:

  ```
  for (String piece : pieces) {
      // do something
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  Iterator<String> iterator = pieces.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      String piece = iterator.next();
      // do something
  }
  ```

  etc.
- iterating through just the first N elements you want if present:

  ```
  Iterator<String> iterator = pieces.iterator();
  if (iterator.hasNext()) {
      String firstPiece = iterator.next();
      // do something
      if (iterator.hasNext()) {
          String secondPiece = iterator.next();
          // do something else
          // etc.
      }
  }
  ```
- using helper functions like those in Guava's [`Iterables`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html):

  ```
  String thirdPiece = Iterables.get(pieces, 2);
  ```

  or

  ```
  String lastPieceOrEmpty = Iterables.getLast(pieces, "");
  ```

  etc.

However, if you'd like to simply access the elements like you would a list you can use [`Splitter.splitToList(CharSequence)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#splitToList(java.lang.CharSequence)) instead. It is the same as `Splitter.split(CharSequence)` but instead of returning a potentially lazy evaluated `Iterable` it returns a populated `ImmutableList` which supports random access to its elements.